# i18next issue translating, when there exists the same translation string with and without period

Tags: javascript, node-modules, i18next

Here is the [i18next](https://www.i18next.com/) config that my company is using. We are using the node module.

```js
i18next.use(sprintf).init({
    lng: language,
    fallbackLng: 'en-US',
    resources: Translations,
    nsSeparator: false,
})
```

In our resource file, we have some translation strings that appear with and without periods. Here is an example of a portion of the resource file for such an occurrence.

```js
{
    ....
    "Done": {
        "": "Done",
        " %1$s is excluded from payroll": {
            "": "Done. %1$s is excluded from payroll."
        },
        " %1$s is included in payroll": {
            "": "Done. %1$s is included in payroll."
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

This causes the following issue when `"Done"` is translated as it is finding an object not a string, since the key `"Done"` fully matches the translation string, but stores an object.

```
key 'Done (en-US)' returned an object instead of string.
```

This same issue occurs for `"Submitting"`, `"Submitting."` and `"Submitting.."` given the following segment of the resource file.

```js
{ 
    ...
    "Submitting": {
        "": {
            "": {
                "": "Submitting..."
            }
        }
    },
    ...
```

I've looked through the [i18next](https://www.i18next.com/) docs, but have failed to find anything that would remedy this other than using a flat file. The architect at my company is opposed to using a flat JSON. I'm wondering if anyone has any thoughts on how to resolve this issue other than using a flat JSON? My company is using [OneSky](https://www.oneskyapp.com/) as our translation service.

Comment: Don't put periods in your translation keys if you don't mean to create a hierarchy.

Comment: These json files looks really strange. Btw: you may try locize.com (by the creators of i18next)

Comment: The json files do look weird. It appears to use `""` to denote a period and creates a new hierarchy, when it hits a period. I'm not sure, if we can easily move to a different service as we are using One Sky in our BE and mobile apps, which have a different setup. Our BE and mobile app setup use One Sky's `.pot` file integration. I am going to reach out to One Sky's support to see if they provide a way to configure the JSON they send back.

Comment: We found a way to configure One Sky's response and that resolved the issue.